# what is "os.dsk cannot be temporal" in pintos?

Tags: linux, pintos

I'm installing Pintos to check if it's installed properly.

[image]

pintos -- run alram-multiple

If I type it, it comes out like that.

i dont know os.dsk..
plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated your sources by running 'source ./activate' command at the very top path of your project?

Answer (score 0):

Did your program compile fine? if not, make sure you defined the functions that you used. but if you did, you probably need to activate a source at the root of the program.